# Using temporary table in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to delete many rows with the same set of field values in some (6) tables. I could do this by deleting the result of one subquery in every table (Solution 1), which would be redundant, because the subquery would be the same every time; so I want to store the result of the subquery in a temporary table and delete the value of each row (of the temp table) in the tables (Solution 2). Which solution is the better one?

First solution:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.SubProtocols
WHERE ProtocolID IN (
    SELECT ProtocolID
    FROM dbo.Protocols
    WHERE WorkplaceID = @WorkplaceID
)

DELETE FROM dbo.ProtocolHeaders
WHERE ProtocolID IN (
    SELECT ProtocolID
    FROM dbo.Protocols
    WHERE WorkplaceID = @WorkplaceID
)

// ...

DELETE FROM dbo.Protocols
WHERE WorkplaceID = @WorkplaceID
```

Second Solution:

```
DECLARE @Protocols table(ProtocolID int NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @Protocols
SELECT ProtocolID
FROM dbo.Protocols
WHERE WorkplaceID = @WorkplaceID

DELETE FROM dbo.SubProtocols
WHERE ProtocolID IN (
    SELECT ProtocolID
    FROM @Protocols
)

DELETE FROM dbo.ProtocolHeaders
WHERE ProtocolID IN (
    SELECT ProtocolID
    FROM @Protocols
)

// ...

DELETE FROM dbo.Protocols
WHERE WorkplaceID = @WorkplaceID
```

Is it possible to do solution 2 without the subquery? Say doing `WHERE ProtocolID IN @Protocols` (but syntactically correct)?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can avoid the subquery in SQL Server with a join, like so:

```
delete from sp
from subprotocols sp
inner join protocols p on
    sp.protocolid = p.protocolid
    and p.workspaceid = @workspaceid
```

You'll find that this doesn't gain you really any performance over either of your approaches. Generally, with your subquery, SQL Server 2005 optimizes that `in` into an `inner join`, since it doesn't rely on each row. Also, SQL Server will probably cache the subquery in your case, so shoving it into a temp table is most likely unnecessary.

The first way, though, would be susceptible to changes in `Protocols` during the transactions, where the second one wouldn't. Just something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Can try this

```
DELETE  FROM dbo.ProtocolHeaders
FROM    dbo.ProtocolHeaders INNER JOIN
        dbo.Protocols ON ProtocolHeaders.ProtocolID = Protocols.ProtocolID
WHERE   Protocols.WorkplaceID = @WorkplaceID
```

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE ... FROM` is a T-SQL extension to the standard SQL `DELETE` that provides an alternative to using a subquery. From the help:

> D. Using DELETE based on a subquery
>   and using the Transact-SQL extension
>   The following example shows the
>   Transact-SQL extension used to delete
>   records from a base table that is
>   based on a join or correlated
>   subquery. The first DELETE statement
>   shows the SQL-2003-compatible subquery
>   solution, and the second DELETE
>   statement shows the Transact-SQL
>   extension. Both queries remove rows
>   from the SalesPersonQuotaHistory table
>   based on the year-to-date sales stored
>   in the SalesPerson table.
>
> ```
> -- SQL-2003 Standard subquery
>
> USE AdventureWorks;
> GO
> DELETE FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory 
> WHERE SalesPersonID IN 
>     (SELECT SalesPersonID 
>      FROM Sales.SalesPerson 
>      WHERE SalesYTD > 2500000.00);
> GO
>
>
>
> -- Transact-SQL extension
> USE AdventureWorks;
> GO
> DELETE FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory 
> FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory AS spqh
>     INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
>     ON spqh.SalesPersonID = sp.SalesPersonID
> WHERE sp.SalesYTD > 2500000.00;
> GO
> ```

You would want, in your second solution, something like

-- untested!
DELETE FROM
    dbo.SubProtocols -- ProtocolHeaders, etc
FROM
    dbo.SubProtocols
    INNER JOIN @Protocols ON SubProtocols.ProtocolID = @Protocols.ProtocolID

### **However!!**

Is it not possible to alter your design so that all the susidiary protocol tables have a `FOREIGN KEY` with `DELETE CASCADE` to the main `Protocols` table? Then you could just `DELETE` from `Protocols` and the rest would be taken care of...

*edit* to add:

If you already have `FOREIGN KEY`s set up, you would need to use DDL to alter them (I think a drop and recreate is required) in order for them to have `DELETE CASCADE` turned on. Once that is in place, a `DELETE` from the main table will automatically `DELETE` related records from the child table.

Comment: Though my tables all do have appropriate `FOREIGN KEY`s, `DELETE CASCADE` would be the best way, I think.

Comment: I just saw this isn't really a DML statement, it's a description to the foreign key. Is there a way to do this in DML?

Answer (score 0):

Without the temp table you risk deleting different rows in the the second delete, but that takes three operations to do.

You could delete from the first table and use the **OUTPUT  INTO** clause to insert into a temp table all the IDs, and then use that temp table to delete the second table.  This will make sure you only delete the same keys with and with only two statements.

```
declare @x table(RowID int identity(1,1) primary key, ValueData varchar(3))
declare @y table(RowID int identity(1,1) primary key, ValueData varchar(3))
declare @temp table (RowID int)

insert into @x values ('aaa')
insert into @x values ('bab')
insert into @x values ('aac')
insert into @x values ('bad')
insert into @x values ('aae')
insert into @x values ('baf')
insert into @x values ('aag')

insert into @y values ('aaa')
insert into @y values ('bab')
insert into @y values ('aac')
insert into @y values ('bad')
insert into @y values ('aae')
insert into @y values ('baf')
insert into @y values ('aag')

DELETE @x
    OUTPUT DELETED.RowID
    INTO @temp
    WHERE ValueData like 'a%'

DELETE y
    FROM @y               y
        INNER JOIN @temp  t ON y.RowID=t.RowID

select * from @x
select * from @y
```

SELECT OUTPUT:

```
 RowID       ValueData
----------- ---------
2           bab
4           bad
6           baf

(3 row(s) affected)

RowID       ValueData
----------- ---------
2           bab
4           bad
6           baf
```

(3 row(s) affected)

Comment: Re »Without the temp table you risk deleting different rows in the the second delete«: I'm executing the whole query in a transaction. Is this still a problem?

Comment: what is after your first delete, but before your second one, someone adds a new item that would qualify for a delete (based on the where condition).  without the temp table you would delete it on the second delete, but it would not have been deleted on the first one.  using the temp table to capture the keys of the actual rows deleted in the first, you will only delete those keys in the second delete.